# How to open object source video in UIView in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiview, facebook-graph-api

I am tracing data from "video" table and I am getting embeded_html. I am showing values in UIView. I want to play video in my view.
Here is my embeded HTML content.

`< object width=\"400\" height=\ "166 \" >< param name=\"allowfullscreen\" value=\"true\" />< param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.facebook.com/v/117758765449600\" />< embed src=\"http://www.facebook.com/v/117758765449600\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" width=\"400\" height=\"166\">< /embed>< /object>`

I have given one space in each `<` tag. How will I open this in video like in youtuve or facebook happens.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you can find the the video source url from the video id using graph api. e.g.

   [https://graph.facebook.com/2031763147233](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=2031763147233)
2. Then you can use UIWebView or MKMoviePlayerController to play the video.